# Find $k \in R$ such that $P\left(\max\left\{\frac{{S_x}^2}{{S_y}^2}, \frac{{S_y}^2}{{S_x}^2}\right\} > k\right)= 0.05$

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, estimation, inference, unbiased-estimator

> Let $\overline{X}$ and $\overline{Y}$ sample means and ${S_x}^2, {S_y}^2$ unbiased estimators for the variance of 2 independent random samples of size 7  with normal distribution with mean unknown and the same variance $\sigma ^2$ known. Find $k \in R$ such that: $$P\left(\max\left\{\frac{{S_x}^2}{{S_y}^2}, \frac{{S_y}^2}{{S_x}^2}\right\} > k\right)= 0.05$$

I know hot to make a confidence interval for $\frac{{\sigma_x}^2}{{\sigma_y}^2}$ but in this case ${\sigma_x}^2={\sigma_y}^2 $ is known, and in this case neither $S_x^2$ nor $S_y^2$ are parameters so I'am confused and have no idea how to do this.

Any hint or idea of how to start?

Comment: If you do post your questions on multiple sites, at least cross-link the posts with each other.

Comment: What has $\overline{X}$ and $\overline{Y}$ got to do with the question?

Comment: Begin by finding the distributions of each quotient.